# Logger on remote server

Tags: syslog, logger

I am trying to send log message to my virtual machine from work station.
Command :

> logger -n 192.168.122.78 Test

After this command nothing shows up in /var/log/messages of VM, or work station. No error, no log message, nothing.

Ping or SSH on address works fine.
Does anybody know what could be wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: is the syslog daemon on 192.168.122.78 configured to accept udp and/or tcp syslog packets from your VM's IP address?    Accept network log packets is disabled by default in most (all?) syslog daemons.

Comment: if you do enable it, you should block incoming tcp & udp port 514 at your firewall.  and/or block that port on the syslog host from all machines except those you explicitly want to be able to log stuff.